# POST json to REST from php

Tags: rest, http-post, dropwizard

I have a REST url (coded in Java using DropWizard) to which I want to POST a json from PHP. However I am getting `415 Unsupported MediaType` error. I have looked up over many forums and I am not able to figure out what the error might be. My code at both ends is as follows:

**SERVER**

```java
@POST
@Path("/update-table")
@Timed
public TableUpdateResponse updateTable(TestClass testObj) {
    LOG.info("inside updateTable function");
    //other code ...
}
```

**CLIENT**

```php
<?php

$url = "localhost:8084/update-table"
$ch = curl_init($url);

$jsonString = array("testString" => "Hello World!");            
$json =  json_encode($jsonString);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

**TestClass**

```java
public class TestClass {
    private String testString;

    public TestClass(String testString) {
        super();
        this.testString = testString;
    }

    public TestClass() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }

}
```

The request is not reaching REST (the LOG line does not get printed). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the application/json content type to one of these

```
application/json
application/x-javascript
text/javascript
text/x-javascript
text/x-json
```

Altough the correct one specified in RFC is application/json, your java code might have a problem with it

Comment: I guess the problem is with the PHP code, because, I tried curl command from terminal and it works.

Answer (score 0):

add the annotation `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`